# How and where is PyTorch's cross-entropy loss implemented?

Tags: python, c++, pytorch

Where is the workhorse code that actually implements cross-entropy loss in the PyTorch codebase?

Starting at [loss.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/9ef1d55e6b85f089f5d1f5a221b2dda4e7c052b2/torch/nn/modules/loss.py#L1032), I tracked the source code in PyTorch for the cross-entropy loss to [loss.h](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/30fb2c4abaaaa966999eab11674f25b18460e609/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn/modules/loss.h#L739) but this just contains the following:

```cpp
struct TORCH_API CrossEntropyLossImpl : public Cloneable<CrossEntropyLossImpl> {
  explicit CrossEntropyLossImpl(const CrossEntropyLossOptions& options_ = {});

  void reset() override;

  /// Pretty prints the `CrossEntropyLoss` module into the given `stream`.
  void pretty_print(std::ostream& stream) const override;

  Tensor forward(const Tensor& input, const Tensor& target);

  /// The options with which this `Module` was constructed.
  CrossEntropyLossOptions options;

  /// A manual rescaling weight given to to each class.
  Tensor weight;
};

/// A `ModuleHolder` subclass for `CrossEntropyLossImpl`.
/// See the documentation for `CrossEntropyLossImpl` class to learn what methods
/// it provides, and examples of how to use `CrossEntropyLoss` with
/// `torch::nn::CrossEntropyLossOptions`. See the documentation for
/// `ModuleHolder` to learn about PyTorch's module storage semantics.
TORCH_MODULE(CrossEntropyLoss);
```

Having looked at the [ModuleHolder](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/classtorch_1_1nn_1_1_module_holder.html) template class, as a C++ newbie, I'm a little lost.

Can someone help me construct an accurate mental model of what is going on here?

Comment: The implementation is in the src folder, not in the includes: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/30fb2c4abaaaa966999eab11674f25b18460e609/torch/csrc/api/src/nn/modules/loss.cpp

Comment: Thanks @luk2302, that gets me part of the way there. This does not seem to be the final source however, since the implementation found there delegates again to [F::detail::cross_entropy](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/30fb2c4abaaaa966999eab11674f25b18460e609/torch/csrc/api/src/nn/modules/loss.cpp#L404). In the end, the correct answer to this question would identify the code where the [cross-entropy formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Definition) can be clearly identified

Answer (score 1):

I found the detailed implementation of cross_entropy_loss_label_smoothing that I need.
But I still can't find the general entry of the function.

path: 'pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/LossNLL.cpp'

```
Tensor cross_entropy_loss_label_smoothing(
    const Tensor& self,
    const Tensor& target,
    const Tensor& weight,
    int64_t reduction,
    c10::SymInt ignore_index,
    double label_smoothing) {
    auto class_dim = self.dim() == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    auto input = at::log_softmax(self, class_dim, self.scalar_type());
    auto nllloss = at::nll_loss_nd_symint(input, target, weight, reduction, ignore_index);

    auto n_classes = input.size(class_dim);

    Tensor smooth_loss;
    if (weight.defined()) {
      // Expand weight to the correct number of dims for broadcasting with input / target
      auto weight_broadcast_shape = SmallBuffer<int64_t, 5>(input.dim());
      std::fill(weight_broadcast_shape.begin(), weight_broadcast_shape.end(), 1);
      weight_broadcast_shape[class_dim] = weight.size(0);
      Tensor weight_ = weight.view(weight_broadcast_shape);

      smooth_loss = -(input * weight_).sum(class_dim);
    } else {
      smooth_loss = -input.sum(class_dim);
    }

    auto ignore_mask = target == ignore_index;
    smooth_loss.index_put_({ignore_mask}, 0.0);

    Tensor ret;
    switch (reduction) {
      case Reduction::Mean:
        if (weight.defined()) {
          // TODO: This code can path can be removed if #61309 is resolved
          // loss is normalized by the weights to be consistent with nll_loss_nd
          ret = smooth_loss.sum() / weight.gather(0, target.masked_select(~ignore_mask).flatten()).sum();
        } else {
          ret = smooth_loss.masked_select(~ignore_mask).mean();
        }
        break;
      case Reduction::Sum:
        ret = smooth_loss.sum();
        break;
      case Reduction::None:
        ret = smooth_loss;
        break;
      default:
        TORCH_CHECK(false, "Invalid reduction type encountered in cross_entropy: ", reduction);
    }
    return (1 - label_smoothing) * nllloss + ret * (label_smoothing / n_classes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74754779/how-and-where-is-pytorchs-cross-entropy-loss-implemented#comment131933747_74754779), the implementation is in the src folder, not in the includes: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/30fb2c4abaaaa966999eab11674f25b18460e609/torch/csrc/api/src/nn/modules/loss.cpp.

Comment: This does not seem to be the case, since the implementation found there delegates again to [F::detail::cross_entropy](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/30fb2c4abaaaa966999eab11674f25b18460e609/torch/csrc/api/src/nn/modules/loss.cpp#L404). In the end, the correct answer to this question would identify the code where the [cross-entropy formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Definition) can be clearly identified.